# How to check if there's a specific charactar in a string (in Python)

Tags: python, string

I am coding a little system for fun right now(in Python). I came into trouble while writing a mail-checker. It is supposed to check if a email address contains a '.' and '@'.
This is the code:

```
def check_mail(mail):
    email = str(mail)
    needed_charachters = ['@', '.']
    if needed_charachters[1] not in email:
        print(send_error('Mail invalid (has to contain ".")'))
        return False
    if needed_charachters[0] not in email:
        print(send_error('Mail invalid (has to contain "@")'))
        return False
    elif '.' in email:
        print('contains .')
```

I already tried a few techniques but there was everytime the same error.
If i put in "ahksdasdhk" as mail there comes my error "has to contain "." "
This is alright and what I wanted. But when mail is "gaagsggg@ksdkj.wssf" there still comes the same error.
Btw this is my code for ther error creator:

```
def send_error(message):
    return f'ERROR: {message}'
```

Comment: You can use regex

Comment: Execute your code manually, with a pen and paper. What happens if email address contains the `.` character but not `@`?

Comment: You can remove the `elif` and just return true

Comment: The problem as posed is incorrect. If you pass the string `gaagsggg@ksdkj.wssf` to `check_mail` then the output is `"contains ."`, not a error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is last **elif '.'**. you can do something like this

```
def check_mail(mail):
    email = str(mail)
    if not email.__contains__("@"):
        print(send_error('Mail invalid (has to contain "@")'))
        return False
    if not email.__contains__("."):
        print(send_error('Mail invalid (has to contain ".")'))
        return False
    # if you passed those steps its valid email so
    return True
```

or simpler

```
def check_mail(mail):
    email = str(mail)
    needed_charachters = ["@", "."]
    err = [x for x in needed_charachters if x not in email]
    err and print(send_error(f"Mail invalid (has to contain '{err[0]}')"))
    return not bool(err)
```

however I myself always verify email like this

```
import re

regex = """^(\w|\.|\_|\-)+[@](\w|\_|\-|\.)+[.]\w{2,3}$"""
is_valid_email = lambda email: bool(re.search(regex, email))

# checking if email is valid or not
print(is_valid_email("the_email_address@info.com"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the technique. The Error was my fault. I used tkinter to get an input but I forgot to write mail.get(). (Befor the fix, mail was 'PY_VAR1'). But now it works.

Answer (score 0):

`elif` is the issue, Try this:

```
def check_mail(mail):
    email = str(mail)
    needed_charachters = ['@', '.']
    if needed_charachters[1] not in email:
        print(send_error('Mail invalid (has to contain ".")'))
        return False
    if needed_charachters[0] not in email:
        print(send_error('Mail invalid (has to contain "@")'))
        return False
    else:
        print('Valid mail')
        return True
```

And  would suggest doing it in a loop:

```
def check_mail(mail):
    email = str(mail)
    needed_charachters = ['@', '.']
    for character in needed_characters:
        if character not in email:
            print(send_error('Mail invalid (has to contain ' + character + ')'))
            return False        
        else:
            print('Valid mail')
            return True
```